# Can not mount /dev/sdb1

Tags: mount, fstab, ubuntu-mate

I can not get /dev/sdb1 to mount in order to see the partition in my file manager. /dev/sdb2 is mounting fine.

This is what I have in fstab.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=81353260-b5a5-4b72-9fce-432e7c620fdc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

#/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MAXTOR_SDB1" UUID="b3b0f384-9e2e-45f5-8995-932f1113f59d" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="000f0791-01"
UUID=b3b0f384-9e2e-45f5-8995-932f1113f59d  ext3  defaults 0


/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

sudo mount /dev/sdb1

mount: ext3: mount point does not exist.

Comment: is the /dev/sdb1 entry supposed to be commented out?

Comment: Well, for one thing there is no mount point defined for that partition. Have you tried mounting it manually with sudo? What happens when you do that?

Comment: @ashvatthama Yeah, it looks like that's just a comment for the next line because it's the same UUID.

Comment: @Sebastian mount: ext3: mount point does not exist.

Comment: You did not specify a place to mount the drive. They sometimes say that "everything in linux is a file" and this is kind of what they are talking about. You have to set a file (or "directory") to mount the drive to. See my example below.

Comment: Exactly. See @mchid 's extended answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [@Sebastian](https://askubuntu.com/users/907096/sebastian), it looks like you have no mount point set for the drive so there is no place for this drive to mount.

When you mount a drive using fstab, you need to specify a mount point.

For example if you look closely at your first entry, you can see that your main drive is mounted at `/`

```
UUID=81353260-b5a5-4b72-9fce-432e7c620fdc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Where would you like to mount the drive? Also, you must make sure that the mount point exists.

If you want to, you can create a mount point to mount the drive to. You could run the following command to create a mount point for the drive:

```
sudo mkdir /media/storagedrive
```

Then, to mount your drive to `/media/storagedrive/`, you would use the following line in fstab:

```
UUID=b3b0f384-9e2e-45f5-8995-932f1113f59d /media/storagedrive/               ext3    defaults 0       0
```

Also, to access this drive, just go to that mount point if it doesn't show up as an extra drive in your file manager.

---

Alternatively, if you want to mount the drive to somewhere in your home directory, you could create a mount point named "extradrive" in your home directory like in this example:

```
mkdir ~/extradrive
```

Then, assuming your username is fixit7, you would use the following line in your fstab file:

```
UUID=b3b0f384-9e2e-45f5-8995-932f1113f59d /home/fixit7/extradrive/               ext3    defaults 0 0
```